# Memory clear with SDWebimagemanager iOS iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, memory, memory-leaks, sdwebimage

I'm very disappointed , it's been over a week since I have this problem of memory and I can not find a solution.

My app uses a lot of high-res photos from facebook.

I use SDwebimageManager to download and cache all my photos.

When I create an instance of my photoviewcontroller there are an average of fourty photos who are downloaded and cached and who appeared on the screen.

As you imagine, I have to clear Cache frequently for each instance of my controller.

But, I have a problem with SDWebimage i can't clear the cache... the size of free physic memory is droping and my app crash always quickly

I'm using storyboard to create the controller like that ( as you can see i clear the cache first ) :

```
if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"FriendView"])
{
    SDImageCache *imageCache = [SDImageCache sharedImageCache];
    [imageCache clearMemory];
    if (self.friends != nil) {
        [self.friends release];
    }
    NSString *s = [friendsid objectAtIndex:indexload];

    self.friends = (MyFriendViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];

    self.friends.friend = s;
    self.friends.Manager = self.Manager; 
}
```

And in the controller I use my manager to download every photo like that :

```
for(int i=0;i<items.count;i++) {
   [self.Manager downloadWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self.items objectAtIndex:i]]
   delegate:self
   options:0
   success:^(UIImage *image,BOOL cached )                        
   {
       [self.photosload setObject:image  forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", i]];
       if (photosload.count == items.count) {
           [self.collectionView reloadData];
       }
   }
   failure:nil];
}
```

I use a NSDictionary to collect all my pictures and when the last photos is downloaded,
I reload my collection view.
If I go back in my ui and I reload my controller, my memory grows and I have a warning very quickly... and the app crashes.

Nothing happen when I clear the memory cache with SDCache.

It's very strange because if i put an [image release] after this line :

```
[self.photosload setObject:image  forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", i]];
[image release];
```

My memory is cleared when I call SDImagecache but  as you can imagine... if i do this...
I use this dictionary "photosload" with a collectionview just after and because I release every image my app crashes when I scroll in the collectionview...

I'm totally disappointed I don't have any idea what's going on...

Thanks really for your help I am totally stuck with this memory problem

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I am wrong, but i think that your problem is in downloading all items, even those you don't need at the moment. Do you have all 40 images on your screen at the same moment? I think you have a collection view with only several on the screen at the same time.

So if I am right, you don't have to download all of them in the loop, download them only when you need them, the most common case is when you are showing a new image. You will reuse UIImageView and fill it with new URL. If you are using [SDImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) library, so you have to load images like this:

```
[imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.items objectAtIndex:i]]
          placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

It should cache your images automatically. You should clear the cache when you receive a memory warning, but that would not be a problem.

This is how `SDImage` works:

When you call `[imageView setImageWithURL:URL placeholderImage:Image];` it checks `memcache` for it, which is just `NSDictionary`, then if there is no such URL in memcache it will search disk for a saved image for this url and if it failed it will start downloading and caching your image. So, you have to use `SDImageCache` only to call `clearMemory` when you receive a memory warning.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I'll try your idea, I do not need 40 images at the same time but I download the images before I reload CollectionView because if I scroll (loading photos are asynchronous and random)  and I see empty cells too long before they became images. I want a perfect user experience when users scroll and I prefer don't have memory warning.. is not possible to clear the cache before memory warning like I have done on my example ?

Comment: just try it, when you do `setImageWithURL ` it cancels previous request if it's in progress, so it should take more time. And I have been using this library before, it worked fine for me.

Comment: hm, you know, you even don't have to call `clearMemory` because `SDImageCache` is an observer for `UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification `, so it will clear memory automatically.

Comment: ok, I'll try, I give you back the answer very quickly Thanks so much !

Comment: another thing i have found is if you want to decrease the size of memcache just put your own number into `SDImageCache` instead of `static natural_t minFreeMemLeft = 1024*1024*12; // reserve 12MB RAM`

Comment: I have done many testing with this minFreeMemLeft but with my example always the same :  crash because my dictionary was empty when the limit arrived  and I don't re-download images. I will increase the mem to 1024*1024*100 with your solution , I'll try Thanks !

Comment: Hi , Im using [image setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:iamgeUrl]
                  placeholderImage:nil
                           options:0
                           success:^(UIImage *image) {}
                           failure:^(NSError *error) {
                               DLog(@"Couldn't download the image, Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
                           }
                   progressBarInfo:pbInfo];
Memory warning and crash happening after 20 scrolls (per scroll i am loading 4 images). I am using ARC , SDImageCache. Though I clear SDImageCache,Its happening:(.

Comment: what is the size of an image you are downloading?